# Parse date with split seconds using read_delim

Tags: r, datetime

Using the `read_delim` function from the `readr` package I would like to parse a csv file including a date time column in the format `2016-12-29 09:00:18.456`, explicitly stating the format.

From the following sources (https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/strptime.html , https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/readr/versions/1.0.0/topics/parse_datetime), I understand that I should use this: `"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS"` as part of the code:

```
a <- read_delim("file.csv", col_names = TRUE, delim = ";", 
                locale = locale(decimal_mark = ","), col_types = cols(
                'Start time' = col_datetime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS")))
```

However, I get the following error:

> ```
> Warning: * parsing failures.
> row        col                     expected                  actual
>   1 Start time date like %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS 2016-12-29 09:00:18.456
> ```

Here is a short reproducible example of the problem:

```
parse_datetime("2016-12-29 09:00:18.456", "%Y-%m-%d H%:M%:%OS")
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `%H` and `%M` rather than `H%` and `M%`?

Comment: @AndrewGustar you're right it should, I will update the question now as the problem is persisting

Comment: Have you tried `%OS3`, as per the strptime link?

Comment: @AndrewGustar I have tried it in this context: ...col_datetime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS3") with the same result

Comment: It might be a conflict with the decimal mark - you declare it as `,` but use `.` in the seconds

Comment: @AndrewGustar I've updated the question with an example of parse_datetime, which should work in the same way, the error is the same, so I think the problem may be independent of the delimiter

Comment: You have the `%` after the `H` and `M` in your example. This works for me.
`parse_datetime("2016-12-29 09:00:18.456", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS")`

Comment: I got mine working by setting `options("digits.secs"=3)`

Comment: @Jake Apologies, copied the example from a pre-typo correction line.  You're right the `parse_datetime("2016-12-29 09:00:18.456", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS")` works fine, still can't get it to work with `col_datetime` maybe Andrew's decimal argument was correct..

Comment: I created a .csv and read it from there and got everything working using `a <- read_delim("Book1.csv", col_names = TRUE, delim = ",", locale = locale(decimal_mark = "."), col_types = cols(
  'DT' = col_datetime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS")))`. I had to open the .csv in Notepad to make sure the date time was formatted correctly. When working with the .csv in Excel it auto-formats the date time and messes it up. So all I changed was your delimiter and decimal mark.

Comment: @Jake, thanks just tried something similar and it's working- Andrew Gustar correct about the delimiter.  If someone want's to write this as an answer I'll happily give the points

Comment: @AndrewGustar Thanks for the help, will happily upvote if you add an answer regarding the delimiter

Comment: @[user632716](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4709298/user632716) good question, as lot of background & references are provided, for other new users.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The decimal mark is inconsistent with the `.` in the seconds.  I also had to set `options("digits.secs"=3)` to get this to work

```
a <- read_delim("file.csv", col_names = TRUE, delim = ";", 
                locale = locale(decimal_mark = "."), 
                col_types = cols(`Start time` = col_datetime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS")))
```

Answer (score 1):

`a <- read_delim("file.csv", col_names = TRUE, delim = ",", locale = locale(decimal_mark = "."), col_types = cols( 'Start time' = col_datetime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%OS")))`

Just need to change your delimiter and decimal mark.